# C++ full system crash, release mode only

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, rendering

I've implemented a specialised tree data structure for a ray tracing application. I'm using an std::list in each of the tree's nodes to store data items. I have a problem where running the application, with this data structure in use, crashes not only the application, but freezes the whole OS (Windows 7). This occurs in release mode only; in debug mode it takes longer (as is expected) but works fine. I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Running (Ctrl+F5) or debugging (F5) in release mode both caused the full system crash.

From what I've found so far, different behaviour between release and debug mode seems to be attributed to memory leaks, as debug mode (from what I've understood) is a little more forgiving. However I've found nothing about a C++ application crashing the OS.

I'd just like to know under what circumstances such behaviour can occur, so I know where to look. It's difficult to reduce the problem to something simple and trace the issue, because it's in the nature of ray tracing to be highly parallel and work with a lot of data.

Oh, and the problem is *not* an infinite recursion causing a stack overflow. I made that happen intentionally and it did not crash the OS.

Comment: Quite the feat to freeze Windows 7 from user-space code. You say it is massively parallel and large amounts of data, could it be that you are running out of resources and that grinds the whole system to near standstill. I have had apps taking down linux machines by running over all available RAM and swap, became a 3 minute task to switch to terminal and try to kill the app.

Comment: If your code is portable, try to compile it on a more stable OS and find the cause of the bug. Debugging by crashing the operating system will take a *long* time.

Comment: If you build the release version with debug information, will it work ok? Otherwise it might help you narrow down the place where the crash happens.

Comment: Also, you don't have any code depending on the `DEBUG`/`NDEBUG` macros?

Comment: Are you using GPU resources?  Try updating the graphics drivers on the machine?

Comment: @r_ahlskog: I thought about running out of resources. It's probably the most probable cause, but also quite unlikely. The tree is supposed to be quite efficient, and also I'd expect the OS to guard against that.
thiton: porting the code would take even longer. Not an option, but thanks for the suggestion.
JoachimPileborg: isn't that the same as debugging in release mode? Still crashes the OS. Re the macros, I don't even know what they are, so I don't think so.
Barry: No, no GPU. Just CPU-based computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the memory usage in the debug mode ? Excessive memory usage and spilling over to   swap would slow down the system like hell - your system might not have technically crashed - just become super slow. And in release mode, all that allocation would be happening at quite some speed - so you might want to look at the memory usage.

And as you said, a infinite recursion will not cause he OS to crash - it always leads to a segmentation fault.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to get at, an application can allocate memory and CPU so fast the scheduler won't even see it coming, once you hit swap/pagefile it is basically game over.

Comment: I just checked in both Debug and Release modes. In Debug mode, the increase in memory is very little and there's plenty to spare. In Release mode, it shoots up and the system freezes. So yes, you were both right about the cause of the crash. But why wouldn't I see the same memory surge in Debug mode?

Comment: Sorry, can't give you a confident reply to that .. but it might have something to do with how the c++ runtime library handles dynamic memory alloc and dealloc in the release mode. A search on those lines might help.

Comment: @user983064 There are some bugs that only show up in release mode, when the compiler optimizes the code. "Strict aliasing" problems are opne example (are you doing evil reinterpret_cast<>s on pointer types somewhere in your code?). Your next step is to narrow down where the problem occurs... on a Linux system, I'd disable swap to make things crash more quickly, don't know if that's an option on Windows.