# C++ release vs debug, memory allocation, skipped constructors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks, constructor

This is a followup of my last question:
[C++ full system crash, release mode only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489641/c-full-system-crash-release-mode-only)

Basically I have a tree-like data structure which, under Release mode, is completely freezing the OS. This occurs due to a sudden surge in memory allocation, which goes beyond what the OS can handle.

This seeming memory leak (which it is, but more on that in a minute) is very weird because I have all the necessary code in place to initialise pointers to NULL and eventually allocate them (when necessary) if they are found to be NULL. In Debug mode, this correct behaviour is confirmed, and things are allocated fine (I can see NULL pointers set to zero from the debugger).

But in Release mode, things are different. The constructors are skipped completely, and all the class's internals are initialised to random garbage. This causes the pointers to go haywire as well, and that's where memory gets allocated until the whole system crashes.

Why is Release mode ignoring my constructors?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 btw.

Comment: Do you really think that the problem is that your constructors are being ignored in release mode?

Comment: Yes, I debugged it and that's exactly what happened. There's a bit too much code to post, but it's more or less based off this: http://www.cmlab.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~wildmb/pbrt/octree_8h-source.html

Comment: Wild guess: Have you tried compiling on the lowest optimization level?

Comment: Do you balance your memory allocations with deallocations? NULL initialization doesn't solve memory leaks, deallocation does. Posting complete code would help.

Comment: Yes, allocation and deallocation is handled exactly as in struct OctNode in the above link. Constructors for both OctNode and Octree are ignored in Release mode.

Comment: In debug mode, there's a place where you think that you're initializing elements to zero, while it's actually done by the compiler. Like others stated, it's probably the lack of an appropriate copy constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from (incomplete) code:

```
template <class NodeData> struct OctNode {
        OctNode() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
                        children[i] = NULL;
        }
        ~OctNode() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
                        delete children[i];
        }
        OctNode *children[8];
        vector<NodeData> data;
};
```

It may leak memory when assigning `OctNode` to another one. The compiler generates the default copy constructor and the assignment operator. The latter may cause memory leaks, because it doesn't deallocate previously allocated memory. I suggest changing the class definition to the following:

```
template <class NodeData> struct OctNode {
        OctNode() : children() {} // zero-initialize children
        ~OctNode() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
                        delete children[i];
        }
        OctNode *children[8];
        vector<NodeData> data;
    private:
        OctNode(OctNode const&);
        OctNode& operator=(OctNode const&);
};
```

And compiling your code. If it doesn't compile because `OctNode& operator=(OctNode const&)` is private, then that was causing a leak.

Comment: Too bad i posted it 43sec later )

Answer (score 3):

The example code you pointed to (http://www.cmlab.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~wildmb/pbrt/octree_8h-source.html) has the `struct OctNode` class managing raw pointers without having an appropriate copy constructor or assignment operator (or havnig them disabled).

`class Octree` contains an instance of `struct OctNode`, so if you have `Octree` objects being copied/assigned there's a good chance that the heap is getting corrupted.

Add the following to `struct OctNode` to disable copy and assignment and see if you start to get linker errors:

```
private:
    OctNode(const OctNode&);
    OctNode& operator=(const OctNode&);
```

However, I can't give a good reason why this wouldn't be causing problems in your debug build as well, so I'm rather skeptical that this will actually be the root of your troubles.

Comment: Finally an answer that sounds plausible. Thanks, I'll see if that fixes things.

Comment: Response to edit: That's true, but if I understood correctly, it does explain why constructors are being skipped (some commenters apparently thought I was crazy for saying it). If not a solution, it's definitely a start.

Comment: I'm not sure it explains why constructor are 'skipped' - what would be happening is that the compiler will automatically create a copy ctor or assignment op that just copies the pointers to the target object. Now you have two objects with the same pointers that will be deleted twice, screwing up the heap. I'd expect that to blow up in debug mode as well, though. The more actual code you can post the better (up to a certain point, of course).

Comment: You know what... it still compiled with private copy and assignment. Oh well. Anyhow, posting any more code than that would do more harm than good. The relevant parts are identical; I would only complicate things by posting all the rest.

Comment: Maybe post code and output from a test `main()` that doesn't do much more than create one or two objects and dump the members, showing the uninitialized pointers.