# C++ and possible hardware failure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, hardware

Can a hardware failure (e.g. RAM corruption) manifest itself as irrational but consistent behaviour in a C++ program?

Today I witnessed very strange behaviour from a program I have been working on for the past year or so. It's written in C++ and I'm using Visual Studio 2010. There were two instances of inexplicable behaviour.

The first involved a particular class's constructor. After I made some code changes (elsewhere, not in the constructor) and rebuilt the project, memory spiked to maximum and froze my OS (similar to a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489641/c-full-system-crash-release-mode-only) I had a year ago which was due to optimisations, but this time optimisations were disabled). Upon debugging, I realised that breakpoints weren't accessible in the constructor, meaning that no code was being generated. If I added a couple of member variables in a struct somewhere else in the code, the constructor magically worked again.

The second instance involved a method A calling a method B and passing a parameter. When debugging, the variable being passed was a valid string before being passed to B. Once at B, the parameter was empty. A system restart made things work fine again.

This made me think that there might be a problem with my RAM - after restarting, the program would maybe run in a different portion of memory, and so not run into problems. The machine I'm working on did experience several blue screens in the past, though not regularly. A run of the Windows memory diagnostic tool did not reveal problems, but I'm still suspicious.

It's easy to blame the environment when you have no clue why things are happening, but I really never saw anything like this before. I just wanted to ask whether it would make any sense for malfunctioning hardware to affect a program like this.

Comment: Does the code run OK on different hardware?

Comment: @juancopanza you beat me to it:)

Comment: That sounds sketchy.  Could your app have any uninitialzed data that may be pointing to random garbage?

Comment: did all of this happen in a debug build? i would tend to assume that you were debugging a debug build, but i'm asking anyway just to stay on the safe side

Comment: No, it's a release build. The nature of the program is such that debug is normally too slow to work with. I did not test on different hardware yet - I'll do that next. Uninitialised data seems unlikely - see comment on Mats Petersson's answer.

Comment: Hardware errors? I think it's far more likely that aliens abducted you and made you write faulty code, produce the output you saw, roll back the changes and then wiped your memory. Why would you jump to such far-fetched hypotheses instead of this much more  obvious one? :-)

Comment: Because faulty code normally has a plausible explanation behind it.

Comment: Yes: The explanation is that you have an error in your code :-)

Comment: Then explain to me how bad code results in code not being generated for a constructor.

Comment: i might be wrong, but if you're debugging a *release* build, i would not be surprised to see bizarre values when inspecting your variables through a debugger, or being unable to set a breakpoint at some particular line (e.g. in a constructor). that does not necessarily mean the values are wrong, or that they are what your IDE tells you. your compiler might have made optimizations. if you want to inspect the runtime behavior of a release build, maybe logging is a safer approach

Comment: Did any answer helped you? Please accept it by clicking in the check mark of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect hardware, you should try another computer. That said, from all the times I actually thought a RAM failure was the reason for a malfunction or compilation problems, none was. The most probable causes are:

- Undefined behavior not just for uninitialized vars but for function paths that don't finish in a return. You should use some kind of Lint.
- Bad compilation scripts or makefiles. You think you are working with library ver X but you are actually linking to some other version Y, or sometimes same version but another not so equal file, specially with different Debug/Test/Release versions.
- Different behavior of libraries when optimized vs. not optimized.
- Threads. Review your writing/read access in every possible scenario. Use some robust and peer reviewed stable library if you can.

Comment: Lower down the list but still possible are compiler bugs. I hit one in VS 2010 just a few months ago. I'd done something in 32-bit builds to make more registers available, and the compiler wasn't restoring EAX after catching an exception. Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you could be quite sure the problem is not your hardware. Otherwise other applications would have incorrect behaviour.

Comment: I tend to agree with you, but I have encountered a case (one in 40 years) where a hardware problem _did_ affect only one program.  The hardware problem involve magnetic core RAM, however (which is sensitive to the pattern of bits written into it), which hasn't been used for quite some time now.

Comment: This sound strange to me since I know that one of the best programs to test RAM is actually running a compiler... hence I would say that in the event of RAM failure one would experience problems not only when running its application but also when compiling it.

Comment: Which failure modes of RAM does running a compiler test?  Different technologies have different failure modes, and require different sorts of tests.  A compiler is certainly _not_ written to exercise any particular failure mode of any particular type of RAM; I rather doubt it would be a particularly good test---probably no better than any other random application.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware faults tend to affect MOST things in the system, not just one application. If you suspect that there is problem with your machine, try running a memory test - this will also test the CPU's behaviour (although that is even less likely to break in a way that only affect some software).

I do believe your software is suffering from "undefined behaviour" rather than hardware fault... You are either writing outside allowed areas, or using uninitialized variables, or something else along those lines. Try to simplify your code, and if you can make it 15-50 lines of code, post here.

Comment: I already did run a memory test (see question). I didn't manage to replicate either problem on a smaller code base. I am doubtful about undefined behaviour - the problems I've encountered are not a result of uninitialised variables. The first one in particular seems to be a compilation issue.

Comment: Ah, missed that. So, not very likely then. Unless your hard-disk is on it's way out. But that seems unlikely. You could always rename your current executable, so that next time you compile, the executable ends up in a different place. If it still fails in a similar way, then you can be pretty sure it's not the hard-disk either [especially if you compare your binaries and they are the same].

Comment: Another thing comes to mind. Two or three times in the past, I've had compilation fail because of some Boost header file. Upon inspection, I found that some random character got inserted right in the middle of the header file, from out of nowhere. Perhaps that could be a hint at impending hard disk failure...

Comment: Either that or you do indeed have a memory failure that only happens sometimes. Try leaving your machine running something like "memtest86+" overnight.

Comment: @Gigi Some random character got _inserted_?  A hardware failure might change a random character (although unless they've changed the way disks work since I worked in hardware, this is highly unlikely), but there's no way it could insert one.